# jquery hide div loaded previously with jquery click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a menu that will show a div when one of the items is clicked by adding the class "visible".

When a second Item is clicked on the menu, it's suppose to hide the previous div by replacing  the class "visible" with hidden"

I am not able to make it hide the previous div and I have tried using if conditionals I guess I'm doing something wrong. I appreciate any help on this.

This is the menu I'm using:

```
<ul class="product_dynamic list_male">
<li><a href="" class="prod_switch_1"><span class="title">option 1</span></a></li>
<li><a href="" class="prod_switch_2"><span class="title">option 2</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Jquery

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
(function (n) {
    $('.prod_switch_' + n).bind('click',function() {
        $('#prod_switch_' + n).removeClass('hidden');
        $('#prod_switch_' + n).addClass('visible');
    });
})(i);
}
```

html

```
<div class="product_display visible" id="prod_switch_1">content</div>
<div class="product_display visible" id="prod_switch_2">content</div>
```

Comment: is the number of menus fixed or dynamic?

Comment: increases by 1 on each item and it doesn't change

Comment: i still didnt follow you i meant are there only 2 `<li>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

Read the question completely wrong the first time :P You shouldn't need to change any HTML, just take a look at this JS.

Use JS to remove the `active` class from all elements before adding it to the clicked one.

JS:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
(function (n) {
    $('.prod_switch_' + n).bind('click',function() {
        $('#prod_switch_' + n).removeClass('hidden');
        $('.product_display').removeClass('visible');
        $('#prod_switch_' + n).addClass('visible');
    });
})(i);
}
```

Comment: lol I noticed. It didn't worked how I wanted but I managed to use it to modified my code and make it work. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted :D

Answer (score 0):

To hide any visible product_display divs on list item on click, try:

```
$('.product_dynamic a').on('click', function(evt) {
  $('.product_display.visible').removeClass('visible'); // hide all visible product_display divs

  var targetID = $(evt.target).attr('class'); // get ID of element to show
  $('#' + targetID).addClass('visible'); // show that element
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".list_male a").click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   $(".product_display").removeClass("visible");//HIDE ALL CONTENTS
   var new_content=$(this).data("content");//GET ID FROM NEW OBJECT TO ADD visible CLASS
   $("#"+new_content).addClass("visible");//SHOW NEW CONTENT
   return false;
});
```

```css
.visible{
  display:block !important;
}

.product_display{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="product_dynamic list_male">
<li><a href="" class="prod_switch_1" data-content="content_1"><span class="title">option 1</span></a></li>
<li><a href="" class="prod_switch_2" data-content="content_2"><span class="title">option 2</span></a></li>
</ul>

<div class="product_display" id="content_1">content 1</div>
<div class="product_display" id="content_2">content 2</div>
```